# Java hash set remove duplicate

Tags: java

The below function returns the product list. Product list should be unique.

The vector ServAttributes stores objects of a custom class. The custom class has a function   getProduct which give the product name that might contain duplicates.

Do I need to scroll through the entire vector, retrieve the object, call the function getProduction and add to the hash set to remove the duplicate product? Vector sometimes stores 400 objects of custom class. Is there any short way of doing the below function?

```
private Vector<ServAttributes> ServAttributes = null;

public HashSet<String> retProduct() {

    HashSet<String> Produset = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int x = 0; x < ServAttributes.size(); x++) {
        ServAttributes record = ServAttributes.get(x);

        if (record.getProduct()) != null) {
            Produset.add(record.getProduct());
        }   

    return Produset;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `Vectors`. :|
Use `List` instead.

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367.  In particular, variables must start with a lower-case letter. You should especially never have a variable that has the exact same name as a class; it's like you're intentionally trying to make it unreadable.  And don't shorten names when it harms readability (ServAttributes vs ServerAttributes, Produset vs products or productSet).

Comment: Vector is List, unless you meant to recommend other implementation of List like ArrayList or LinkedList

Answer (score 1):

With a general-purpose helper library like Guava, you could do this in a functional way:

```
return Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.filter(Iterables.transform(serverAttributes, new Function<ServAttributes, String>() {
    public void apply(ServAttributes attributes) {
        return attributes.getProduct();
    }
}), Predicates.notNull()));
```

With stock Java, there are a couple of improvements you can make.  You can use the enhanced for loop for starters:

```
for ( ServAttributes attributes : serverAttributes ) {
    productSet.add(attributes.getProduct());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't skip products which are `null`.

Comment: @BalusC: I'm not interested in rewriting his method for him.  I was showing him how to use the enhanced for-loop.  But I'll update the Guava example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `ServAttributes` class, then overrride `equals` and `hashCode` methods, then use the following code to remove the duplicate:

Note: This returns HashSet of `ServAttributes`. If you need only the product name, then you will have to iterate through the vector.

```
HashSet<ServAttributes> noDub= new HashSet(new LinkedHashSet(ServAttributes));
```

In `ServAttributes` class override the `equals` and `hashCode` as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return product.hashCode();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if(obj instanceof ServAttributes) {
        ServAttributes s1 = (ServAttributes)obj;

        if(s1.getProduct().equals(this.getProduct())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```